# Build standalone windows exe without dependency on unityplayer.dll and Data folder?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to publish my game on itch using butler but I cant see how to generate an actual standalone windows executable rather than the default game exe, unityplayer.dll and _data folder.

I can zip all the required and upload that for the itch web store, but the itch windows app doesn't support these.

Comment: That dll and folder are your game. You can't get around this as far as I know.

Comment: @Draco18s do you know how people manage to publish their games to itch/steam?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNAKV.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCved.png In terms of what they do on the publisher backend? No idea, never messed with it. But I can tell you that that dll and _data folder are still there.

Comment: For itch.io, you upload a zip file containing everything. If it's a WebGL build, you zip up the index.html and _data folders.

Comment: @Draco18s Does your game work when installed and launched from the itch windows app? The zip works for the web download, but no the itch.io desktop app install/launcher.

Comment: I've never used it. I only have projects up in a webgl format to use for the purposes of a portfolio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make an installer into a seperate exe, or just self extracting zip file, but data folder and unity.dll are parts of the engine, as far as I know you need them present

Comment: Yep, looks like you have to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Even shipping games work this way; for example, I checked my Steam folder, and there's a ton of unityplayer.dll and data folders.

```
3/02/2019  12:57         <DIR>    steam_shader_cache
6/06/2018  21:25         <DIR>    ArizonaSunshine_Data
5/25/2018   2:50         <DIR>    MonoBleedingEdge
5/25/2018   2:31      22,281,152  UnityPlayer.dll
5/25/2018   2:31       1,426,880  UnityCrashHandler64.exe
5/25/2018   2:29         648,704  ArizonaSunshine.exe
6/26/2017  20:27         <DIR>    _CommonRedist
```

I know why you want to do this, I'm assuming to hide the fact you're using Unity, and to make everything 'simple' for people to run. The former is tough, the latter is absolutely required. I sent a .zip file to a friend who swore that he had unzipped the file and put it on his desktop. The "myapp.exe" kept asking for Unity and a license.

He was double-clicking on the .exe inside the .zip file, which looks like a folder on Vanilla Windows.

So, after having said that, I highly recommend using a real installer program.

A "real" installer, like http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php, will make it easier for people to just load your program like a 'real' program, and hide the .dll file and associated mess.